# Jquery to populate input or textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="example"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
             jah = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
             jah+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
             jah+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
             jah+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
             jah+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
             jah+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

             document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=jah;

             </script>
```

I'm using the above code to compile some browser info I need to collect from a form.  How can I get that info passed to a Input or Textarea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm slightly confused because you asked for jQuery in the title, but then your example is all about pure javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use pure JavaScript instead of jQuery, try this:

```
<form><textarea id="ta"></textarea></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jah = "whatever you want";
    var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
    ta.value = jah;
</script>
```

Assigning `.value` equals jQuery function `.val(v);`

Answer (score 25):

By using [`$.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Assuming `#example` is a selector pointing to the input field in question, you can use something like this:

```
$('#example').val(jah);
```

Answer (score 2):

just like this using jQuery's [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method `$('#Id').val(jah);`

Where Id is the id of input for textarea. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myinput').val($('#example').find('p').text());
```

where 'myinput' is id of your textarea. Paste this line after

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=jah;
```