# Rails: How do I inject form information on click?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a basic form in rails:

```
<% form_for shipping_object do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :address1, :placeholder => "Address Line 1*", :class => "forms" %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :address2, :placeholder => "Address Line 2", :class => "forms" %>
<%= f.collection_select :state_id, @states.where(country_id: f.object.country_id).order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: '-- select state --'  %>
<%= f.text_field :state_name, placeholder: 'State', class: 'forms' %>
<%= f.text_field :zipcode, :placeholder => "Zip Code*", :class => "forms" %>
<% end %>
```

I'd like to have a UI/UX checkbox element that a user can click and have all the form areas populated with pre-defined variables, but I'm not sure how I would do that.  I'm assuming it's done with .attr methods in Javascript, but I'm not sure how?

Comment: Have you looked into setting a JS listener for the checkbox, then [filling the form with the data using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10545605/3878329)?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formal answer for people who stumble upon this in the future:

Pass the data from Rails to the JavaScript while the page is being rendered and have a JS listener that listens to when the checkbox is clicked. When this listener is fired, [fill in the form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545573/jquery-to-populate-input-or-textarea/10545605#10545605).